# In React, if a dependency is changed to the same value, does useEffect get fired?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose we have this:

```
const [number, set_number] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [number]);
```

What if some computation did that:

```
set_number(2 - 1);
```

Will the useEffect get trigged in this case?

Answer (score 7):

> In React, if a dependency is changed to the same value, does useEffect
> get fired?

No it does not, the purpose of dependencies is to fire effect when *at least one* of its dependencies *changes* (i.e. has different value than it had on previous render). From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects):

> You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values
> haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an
> optional second argument to useEffect